# How using CSS to select last level hierarchy elements?

Tags: css

This is my code:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            ... (There can be many other nested elements ul li)
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to using CSS to select last level hierarchy elements li (the result is that the li elements contain a and b) without knowing level hierarchy

CSS is possible if available:
`ul * li:last-hierarchy`

Result the selected elements should be:

```
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
```

Comment: why not just `ul ul li`

Comment: This is the focus of the question:
"... (There can be many other nested elements)"

Comment: What are nested elements though? if it's other tags then it hardly matters right, since you only want `li`?

Comment: you want last hierarchy value or you want to apply css ?

Comment: @Kiran Mistry, yes

Comment: my question is that what you want  ?

Comment: in this case, the hierarchy you are having, ul > li {css} will work, as I can see if there is content then no other nesting is there, and if nesting is there then content will not.

Comment: I want to apply style to element li last (contain a and b)

Comment: Can you explain why your situation wouldn't allow you to add classes?

Comment: lets do one thing if you can, make it nested as much as you want, just add some more elements, and then it would be easy to solve it...

Comment: My html content is copied from a third party, so the format is not the same every time.

Comment: let me create an example for you, just confirm one thing, the nested hierarchy will always be UL LI right?

Comment: What you want is not possible, _“without knowing level hierarchy”_ There is no CSS selector to directly express what you want, so you can only achieve this by having the full “chain” of parent elements combined with `>` in your selector.

Comment: Content can nest elements other  then ul li

Comment: if it can be other than UL LI then its not possible with css as Cbore mentioned above